# How can I specify different working directories in qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using the latest QT SDK under Windows and am wondering how I specify a working directory based on the build type.  I need a different working directory and release and debug builds of the same project.  For instance, I have a run target called MyProgram and two build targets, Release and Debug.  MyProgram depends on some external libraries.  When I run MyProgram in debug I need it to run in the directory C:\foo\bar\libraries\debug, however when I run it in release I need it to run in directory C:\foo\bar\libraries\release.  It would appear that the Working Directory is only dependent on the run target and not on the build target.  Is there a way to specify a Working Directory based on both run and build target?  Could I use a variable to specify release/debug in the Working Directory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Delete the .pro.user file in the project directory, open the project, and set "Create build configurations" to manually, and check "Use shadow building". Now you can specify the target directories.
BTW, for a better solution for your missing libs, check out the Qt resource system: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/QResource.html

Comment: This seems to work if I don't manually want to then edit the Working Directory.  However, in my case, I have a bunch of binaries that all share the same libraries, so I have to make the Working Directory /debug for all debug binaries, and /release for all release binaries.  As soon as I edit the working directory then it becomes the same for both debug and release.